# How to use dotenv to add Environment Variables to ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, production-environment

I want to set `SECRET_KEY_BASE` which is used in `secrets.yml`:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I have tried to add code as follow in `.profile`:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=cfbc3b45d65db30b853cdc0557e0be85609cf75974ebb706f46a00abe09eee9454b3d311e48ee4157e1e5d5e3de5b8d2a329dff13871837cbaeae6af2bc2e42f
```

it works well, but this is still not that better, I know that `dotenv` can add this in a `.env` file in root path of app, so I add

```
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'dotenv-deployment'
```

then I add code as follow into `.env.production` in root path of rails app:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=cfbc3b45d65db30b853cdc0557e0be85609cf75974ebb706f46a00abe09eee9454b3d311e48ee4157e1e5d5e3de5b8d2a329dff13871837cbaeae6af2bc2e42f
```

But why this doesn't work?

Comment: are you populating the `.env` file too?

Comment: @alf no, do I need this?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but by looking at the source code it seems that the `.env` file is required and it should contain default values that can be shared and committed to the repo and work for the dev environment. Then you override those values in `.env.#{environment}`.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4.1, config/secrets.yml is the new default location for secret_key_base of your application. It can, however, be used also for storing other secret variables, making it a good place for environment-specific tokens, API keys etc.

Fill the file with the secrets you want to store, for example:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: your_development_secret
  api_key: some_key
production:
  secret_key_base: your_production_secret
  twitter_consumer_key: production_twitter_key
  twitter_consumer_secret: production_twitter_secret
  twitter_oauth_token: production_oauth_token
  twitter_oauth_token_secret: production_oauth_secret
```

In your code, you can access these secrets with Rails.application.secrets:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_consumer_key
  config.consumer_secret    = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_consumer_secret
  config.oauth_token        = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_oauth_token
  config.oauth_token_secret = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_oauth_token_secret
end
```

The secrets.yml will be checked into git by default, add it to your .gitignore file.